# Quarkus: Exclude certain paths from being logged in OTel (Open Telemetry)

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry

In my Quarkus app, I have 2 paths I do not want to show in my OTel collector, `/check` (for health check) and `/q/metrics` (for Prometheus metrics), because they're just noise. How do I do that?

Note: I use automatic instrumentation.

Comment: What do you mean by automatic instrumentation? You are using the OTel agent or the `quarkus-opentelemetry` extension?
Which Quarkus version?
The recommended way to use OTel in Quarkus is through the `quarkus-opentelemetry` 
 extension.

Comment: you can try whis approch is Quarkus supports it (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/annotations/#suppressing-withspan-instrumentation)

Comment: the `quarkus-opentelemetry` extension already does that exclusion out of the box.